# R error: 'as.list.reactivevalues' is deprecated. Use reactiveValuesToList instead. Please see ?reactiveValuesToList for more information

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a Shiny app that will take a word as the input and predict the next word, based on information I have from blogs, news, and twitter. I have created ngram.rds that involved making a corpus, then tokenizing it, and finally creating an ngram.

This is what I have on my server.R for my Shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(tm)
library(data.table)
library(quanteda)
library(dplyr)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  setwd("/Users/alishaqazi/Downloads")

   wp<- reactive({ 
      ngram <- readRDS("ngram.rds")
      y <- kwic(ngram, input)
      ydt <- as.data.table(y)
      ychar <- as.character(ydt)
      ydfm <- dfm(ychar, remove_punct=TRUE, remove_numbers=TRUE)
      w <- textstat_frequency(ydfm)
      wordPrediction <- w[[2,1]]
  wordPrediction
  })

 output$wordPrediction <- renderPrint({
           wp()
   })
})
```

It seems to be working, but it takes a very long time to produce a result, and also gives me this error which I do not understand:

```
'as.list.reactivevalues' is deprecated. Use reactiveValuesToList instead.
Please see ?reactiveValuesToList for more information.
```

Would anyone know how to help me with this? I do not know where the error is coming from or if this is the reason it is running very slowly.

Please let me know as soon as you can! This is for something I have to turn in tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. That's a weird error. I guess something about all the word stuff you're doing is making a list, and Shiny doesn't like as.list() being called on a reactive. I suppose after a while of being deprecated it will eventually stop working.

I highly doubt it's making it run slowly, though. It's just saying it's deprecated, "don't do this". On its own that shouldn't make the code slow. The ngram stuff is probably making it run slowly. Try it outside of Shiny to check if you're bothered. I don't know if this is a cut down example, but in your cut down example Shiny isn't doing anything at all anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It could be the ngram stuff for sure. When I run this in the R console it gives me an answer very quickly, but in the shiny app it just takes a very long time.

Comment: I am also having trouble just uploading it to shiny as well. I thought it may be the setwd() part, so I adjusted that so that the ngram.rds is in the folder with the ui and the server, but now it is giving me an error that says Error: HTTP 404
GET https://api.shinyapps.io/v1/applications/277342
Not Found
In addition: Warning message:
In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2017c.1.0/zoneinfo/America/Chicago'
Execution halted